# Сумма чисел от единицы до введённого

Tags: javascript

Рассчитайте сумму чисел от 1 до введённого числа, то есть 1+2+3+4+…+введённое_число.

Я понимаю, без цикла тут не обойтись. Если не сложно оба реализовать (`for, while`).

Comment: без цикла обойтись. вам [сюда](https://ru.khanacademy.org/video?lang=ru&format=lite&v=m6jRE5suKZA).

Comment: это просто гениально!!!

Comment: Я имел ввиду реализовать данный код на языке js, а не по алгебраически (арифметическая прогрессия). Возможно вы не понели мне нужно что бы пользователь ввел число к примеру (5) и все целые числа от 1 до 5 сложились. И все это нужно сделать через цикл любой из двух который я написал. После чего скрипт должен выдать ответ.

Comment: Вот так? 

     var n=5; s=(n+1)*n/2; while(false){}; console.log(s);

или так еще можно...

     var n=5; s=(n+1)*n/2; for(;false;){}; console.log(s);

Comment: Да, Спасибо! И как правильный ответ указать (Вас) просто Вы подписались не в ответ, а как цитируя. Что в это случает делать. Я просто около 2,5 ч. назад зарегистрировался.

Comment: @Castle540 - тупо решать циклом, то что можно посчитать по формуле.

Comment: Я учусь программировать  и стараюсь задействовать все варианты - разве это плохо. И вообще перед мной была поставлена задача я ее попросил реализовать. Я же не для тебя пишу, а по пройденной теме для себя.

Comment: А вы не задумались что если задача поставлена перед вами то нужно ее решить именно вам а не списать ответ из интернета?) иначе мало похоже на то что вы учитесь.

Comment: <p><a href="/users/10415/torch565">@ToRcH565</a> Хорошо, а что если не удается решить задачу, что подскажите делать? И не хотите поделиться, как вы сами обучались? И для чего тогда существуют форумы и сообщества как это. А вот еще я только вчера зарегистрировался и меня уже рейтинг уважения упал. Не понимаю, что все такие злые. В место того чтобы объяснить человеку вы обливаете грязью (я не про вас). 
</p>

Comment: @Castle540, если вы не можете решить _эту_ задачу, то вы, по всей видимости, даже не пытались читать хоть какие-нибудь учебники по JavaScript, а даже если и читали, то не пытались понять. Потому что циклы (забудем про то, что эту задачу можно решить математически) это одна из основных и самых простых конструкций языка. Здесь помогают людям, которые могут и хотят учиться, а не тем, кто даже не пытается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S = n * (a_1 + a_n) / 2,
где S - искомая сумма, n - количество суммируемых элементов, a_1 и a_n - начало и конец диапазона.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var sum = 0, var step = 1; step < to; step++  ) {
sum+=step;
}
```

Comment: а разве можно условие ставить в конце в for-e, а инкримент перед ним ??

Answer (score 0):

вот только http://jsfiddle.net/6uSDN/1/