# Как посчитать сумму чисел в цикле for?

Tags: javascript, for

Условие задачи:
Напиши функцию calculateTotal(number), которая принимает целое число (параметр number) и возвращает сумму всех целых чисел от единицы и до этого числа. Например, если number равно 3, то сумма это 1 + 2 + 3, то есть 6.

мой вариант не считает сумму, а просто перебирает от заданного числа:

```js
    function calculateTotal(number) {
  
  for (let i = 0; i <= number; i += 1) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
console.log(calculateTotal(3));
```

подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно поправить чтобы считало правильно?

Comment: так может стоит завести переменную, в которой считать сумму и на каждой итерации прибавлять к ней число вместо вывода? Или вы как-то иначе представляете себе подсчет суммы?

Comment: В задаче, кстати, не заставляют использовать цикл. Это арифметическая прогрессия, для которой есть решение в одну строчку ;)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME вероятно задача из главы про цикл for

Comment: что-то вроде этого? function calculateTotal(number) {
  
  let sum = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i <= number; i += 1) {
  sum += i;
    }
    console.log(sum);
}

Comment: вроде этого. `return sum` только в конце. Можно сократить до `for(var i=0, sum=0; i<= num; sum+=i++); return sum;`

Comment: благодарю) все получилось

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помогите реализовать скрипт (новичок!)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/247581/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%be%d0%ba)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function calculateTotal(number) {
  let sum = 0;

  for(let i = 1; i <= number; i++){
    sum += i;
  }

  return sum;
}

console.log(calculateTotal(3))
```